# How do I predict survival curves using xgboost?

Tags: xgboost, survival-analysis

The xgboost package enables survival modeling using parameter arguments: objective = "survival:cox" and eval_metric = "cox-nloglik".

The predict method for the resulting model only outputs risk scores (same as `type = "risk"` in the `survival::coxph` function in r).

How do I use xgboost to predict entire survival curves?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proportional hazard model assumes hazard rates of the form: $h(t|X) = h_0(t) \cdot risk(X)$ where usually $risk(X) = exp(X\beta)$. The `xgboost` predict method returns $risk(X)$ only. What we can do is use the `survival::basehaz` function to find $h_0(t)$.

Problem is it's not "calibrated" to the actual baseline hazard rate computed in `xgboost`. What we can do is find some constant $C$ that minimizes the ibrier score between the sample observed death/censorship times and $h_0(t) \cdot risk(X) \cdot C$.

I've implemented this approach in a tiny R package I've [written](https://github.com/IyarLin/survXgboost).

Comment: How to calculate C-index in this setting? Can your package accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: My package does not include that functionality. I would recommend using either the `pec` or `riskRegression` packages

Comment: How do censorship times contribute to the ibrier score?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The ibrier score is a function of the estimated and observed survival functions, in which censorship times also take a role.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to use `survival::basehaz()` with a coxph model and estimate a constant C, as implemented by [survXgboost](https://github.com/IyarLin/survXgboost) should be used with caution. When you have binary predictors, `coxph` coefficients explode, leading to really overestimated baseline hazard, the constant C will not do much and the performance of xgboost will look much worse than what it really is.

The `gbm` package has a function `gbm::basehaz` which skips the model, avoiding the compatibility problem that you have in `survival::basehaz()`, and uses the `predict()` results to estimate the baseline hazard. It is more reliable and the (cumulative) baseline hazard is as expected.

Comment: Note that `gbm::basehaz` returns the Breslow estimator. This can be done using `survival::survfit` and specifying `stype = 2` as well, which skips the dependency on gbm (as most R users working with survival data will use the survival package).

Comment: I've used the advice from this thread and it's now incorporated to the code. Thanks @ErikA for your contribution.